# html2canvas exports wrong font in svg

Tags: javascript, svg, fonts, html2canvas

in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshncc/ncv56vwf/) there is a basic example of my problem. The exported image contains text whose font is different from the one used in the source. How can I solve this problem?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#export').on('click', function() {       
        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="export" value="Export"/>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<text x="162" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" zindex="4" style="color:#333333;font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:normal;font-family:Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;visibility:visible;fill:#333333;width:260px;" y="25">Inventory</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Technical note: SVG elements on HTML5 pages are part of the HTML5 spec, and the tags do not need namespacing or namespace declarations in the svg root element. In fact, the only tag that *uses* a namespace prefix is `xlink:href`, and because it is the only one, it does not need the xlink namespace definition in the SVG scope. On a practical note: font families with spaces or special characters need to be quoted. You can't say `font-family: Lucida Grande`, for example, that needs to be `"Lucida Grande"`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did what you said about font families with spaces, but it didn't work

Comment: I don't have those Lucida fonts, but if I use "Dejavu Sans", which I do have installed, it works fine: http://jsbin.com/tihenazolo/edit?html,css,output -- always make sure that if you're using a font that is not in the "Default browser-safe list of fonts", you use a `@font-face` rule to explicitly load that font.